# Triggering segues from annotations

Tags: objective-c, annotations, storyboard, autolayout, segue

I found that a previously normally working iPad storyboard started working weirdly upon introducing auto-layout. In particular it seems not to properly show different ViewControllers when clicking different annotations but instead it always shows the first one whatever more annotations are clicked. When I disable auto-layout everything works fine again. Apple responded to my request hinting to a problem in the handling of segues:

@Apple: 'When running a segue from A -> B, it is not our intention that that segue over and over again will result in a chain like A -> B -> C -> D because the original transition is A -> B. However it would make sense if you had a self-referencing segue and you called performSegueWithIdentifier over and over again because you in that case are having the same instance just added to itself. I think you were just getting lucky before and that turning auto layout on was just enough to point that out.'

Yet all the hits I found on the web like in:
[How to call a segue from a disclosure button on a map pin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825496/how-to-call-a-segue-from-a-disclosure-button-on-a-map-pin)
and
[MKMapView show DetailView - How to make a segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741334/mkmapview-show-detailview-how-to-make-a-segue)
are quite the same as the the code I used and Apple says it is wrong; notwithstanding the iPhone version keeps on working and the problem just arises on the iPad.

Any hint before they crank up another funny suggestion?

Comment: I even opened a technical incident. This problem is lingering for one month now. Any hint from StackOverlow? Otherwise I will of course post the eventual answer by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the problem, the way it went the way it returned. Eschewing the possibility I ran mad, the same code including the one on the iTunes Store now, started presenting the problem again. I also tested it on another iPad and it presents the same problem leaving me totally in the dark. All the thing seems crazy.

Comment: Now the problem disappeared on the test iPad mini but stayed on my iPad, even downloading again the app from iTunes. I am dumb folded. Could someone tell me if he could test on his iPad with a promo code.

Comment: Also I found that even in my iPad, after clicking a new annotation and having the old view controller, waiting for a while the correct controller is shown. Like if the viewWillAppear were somehow delayed. Two other controllers of a different kind do not seem to be refreshed, though, even waiting.